# No checkpoint file found at inception-v3

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow-serving

When I am trying to run this script on conda environment I am getting the error that no checkpoint file found at inception-v3 ,

-> bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_export --checkpoint_dir=inception-v3 --export_dir=inception-export

Please anybody help me with this issue I will be thankfully to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the documentation of `inception_export`, you need to provide the directory where you have your model checkpoint. Do you have a valid inception-v3 checkpoint in `tensorflow_serving/example/inception_exportinception-v3/`?

If not, you should download a model checkpoint to use.